# I'm creating CRUD functions and I keep getting an error when I click my Delete button, is my SQL code right?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, crud

//If you click a row it will be deleted

```
 string sqlStr = "DELETE from Members MemberID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Mobile, Email, Address, Suburb, City, PostalCode, DateJoined;";
 sqlStr += "WHERE rowid=@Rowid;";
```

Comment: first you need to learn sql syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sqlStr = "DELETE from Members WHERE rowid=@Rowid";
```

Comment: that is what i originally had but my tutor said it was wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `;` at the and of the first line. And remove those field names.
Just use

```
"delete from members where rowid=@Rowid"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you should do like this:

```
string sqlStr = "DELETE from Members";
 sqlStr += " WHERE rowid=@Rowid;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for DELETE operation does not require column names to be included.

```
DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE <condition>
```

In your case it will be,

```
string sqlStr = "DELETE from Members WHERE rowid=@Rowid";
```

I am assuming that you already have `@Rowid` declared and assigned as `SqlParameter`